# Is it possible to decode and analyze HDMI in on Android devices?

Tags: android, hdmi, hdcp

This has been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15534175/capturing-audio-frames-from-hdmi-in-port).  Since then the HDCP master key has been leaked.  Is it still nearly impossible to read HDMI input to opencv?

An example device with HDMI input is the [Geniatech ATV1610](http://www.geniatech.com/pa/atv1610.asp).  This looks a lot like the device that [skipr](http://www.techhive.com/article/2894375/skipr-shows-off-the-first-android-tv-box-with-cable-tv-pass-through.html) uses.

Edit: How about non-hdcp sources?  Anyone?

Comment: Just so you know about Intel's feelings about the master key: http://www.wired.com/2010/09/intel-threatens-consumers/

Comment: It seems like intel is after companies that produce hardware that bypasses copy protection.  I'm just trying to use an android device to analyze HDMI on the fly, something like a modern version of the [Arduino Video Experimenter Shield](http://www.robotshop.com/en/video-experimenter-arduino-compatible-shield.html).

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because the source device will not send a valid signal to the sink, unless the sink device correctly negotiates a connection with the source. This requires both a valid KSV (40-bit Key Selection Vector) (one that has not been revoked by DCP LLC) as well as valid device keys that correspond to the KSV.

Given that this HDCP handshake is typically done by the same hardware that subsequently decrypts the stream, you find yourself in an all-or-nothing situation. You either have a valid KSV and corresponding sink keys, in which case you can do the handshake **AND** the decryption. Or you don't, in which case you can not negotiate the link handshake and the source will not send you any data, encrypted or otherwise.